# Create a Angular project with specific version

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have installed Angular CLI 1.7.0

When I create a project using

```
ng new myProj
```

it creates a project with Angular 5.2.0.

From package.json

```
@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
```

However, I need to create a project with Angular version 5.1.3.

How can I do this with CLI?

Reason I need to go for a lower version is this error

```
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21670
```

I am facing the exact same error and suggested solution is to downgrade to 5.1.3.

How can I use CLI to create a 5.1.3 project?

Comment: Why not just update the `package.json` file after the creation?

Answer (score 0):

You will either have to install an older version of the cli, or downgrade the angular dependencies in the package.json by hand and reinstall the node_modules afterwards. There is no Parameter for the cli in order to install older dependencies.

Comment: I can change the version of angular dependencies by hand in package.json. So, all angular related packages I have changed to 5.1.3 in package.json. However, how would I know what would be the correct version of some of the other packages to be used when using angular 5.1.3. For instance, rxjs is currently 5.5.6, zone.js is  0.8.19, core-js is 2.4.1 in package.json. Now that I have manually changed the value of angular to 5.1.3, how do I know what should these packages be set to?

Comment: The easiest way would be to check out what a fresh project, created with an older version of the cli, puts in its package.json and take those values as a reference. The harder way would be to check out all compatibilities by hand by simply googling it. So to say the same way you would have to go if there was no ng cli in the first place. Just as if you would put together your project by hand.